# Embeds not working

Tags: embeds, ee3

I building a super simple site on EE 3.0.3. and am having a seemingly weird issue where my embeds are not loading. I'm sure it something simple but I'm not able to see what is going wrong. The live site is at http://vanessareynoldsmd.com and here's the code for the index page

```
{embed="includes/header"}

  <header class="book-page">
    <div class="container">
     <h1>An Apple A Day - 100 Quick Devotionals When Pressed for Tim</h1>

     <p class="tagline-1">Five inspiring testimonials</p>
     <p class="tagline-2">100 Daily Devotions</p>
     <p class="tagline-3">A daily dose of spiritual nutrition</p>
     <p class="tagline-4">A new book written by<br /> <em> Vanessa Reynolds M.D.</em></p>

     <h3 class="button-wrapper">
       <a class="buy-button paperback" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1501073362">Buy The Paperback</a>
       <a class="buy-button ebook" href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QJ9VBCM">Buy The eBook</a>
     </h3>

     <img src="/assets/media/logo-book.png" class="book" title="An Apple A Day book cover" />
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <section class="description">
      <h2 class="section_title">Thought of the Week</h2>

      {exp:channel:entries channel="articles" limit="1"}
      {article_excerpt}

      <p class="aricle-date"><a class="btn btn-continue pull-right" href="{url_title_path="articles/read"}" role="button">Continue Reading</a></p>
      {/exp:channel:entries}

      {exp:channel:entries channel="general_pages" limit="1"}
      {speaking_engangment}
      <h2 class="section_title top_gap">Next Speaking Appearance</h2>
      <h4 class="speaking-name">{speaking_engangment:location_name}</h4>
      <h4 class="speaking-address">{speaking_engangment:location_address}</h4>
      <h4 class="speaking-date">{speaking_engangment:date_time}</h4>
      {/speaking_engangment}
      {/exp:channel:entries}
    </section>

    {embed="includes/newsletter" color="sidebar-dark"}

{embed="includes/footer"}
```

and here's the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>{if embed:title}{embed:title} /{/if} Vanessa Reynolds, MD</title>

  <!-- Meta Tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Just as an apple a day provides the nutrition your body needs, this uplifting daily devotional works to inspire spiritual growth as you reflect on bite-size doses of Christian wisdom and apply the important lessons within to your own life.">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/media/favicon.ico" />

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="/assets/styles/build/base.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        MENU
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Vanessa Reynolds, MD</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li {if "{segment_1}" == "about"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{path="about"}">About</a></li>
        <li {if "{segment_1}" == "articles"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{path="articles"}">Articles</a></li>
        <li {if "{segment_1}" == "book"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{path="books"}">The Book</a></li>
        <li {if "{segment_1}" == "messages"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{path="messages"}">Messages</a></li>
        <li {if "{segment_1}" == "contact"} class="current"{/if}><a href="{path="contact"}">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I can't seem to locate what I'm missing that would cause these not load.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know this is stupid but... you triple checked your filenames/spelling, and made sure they exists in the template group called "includes"? Also, EE3 has so far proven to be buggy and not worth jumping on board with yet (IMHO).

Comment: Totally valid question. I have have triple checked, but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Pressed for Tim?

Comment: Any improvement when you take out the conditional?  Doesn't look like you are passing embed:title anyway...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a NEW template, all access is set correctly (access for all groups).
When you DUPLICATE a template, all access is removed except for Super Admins.

Comment: This is considered a bug and will be fixed in an upcoming release. (https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21418/)

Answer (score 0):

I knew it had to be something simple. It was a permission issue. For some reason none of the member groups were checked. Once I allowed all the member groups things were working as expected.  [image]